# How to convert a Date to OLE Automation Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, ole

I need to pass a Date value to a .Net server which expect to receive **OLE Automation Date value** (Microsoft Timestamp - a decimal value).

Any idea how to convert a Javascript Date to this format in JS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) but I don't think that's a good practice. I think it is better to pass an standard date format (like ISO) and then in your .NET application convert it to OLE Automation Date format, this way the front part is not coupled to your database.